How to input a variable from an insert statement into the json value in PSQL?
I want this statement to insert the variable data in my psql statement but I do not know how to initialize the data within the json statement.
INSERT INTO audit_log (
  action, 
  result, 
  input_data, 
  output_data, 
  sponsor_id, 
  user_id)
VALUES(
  1020, 
  1, 
  '{"Sponsor id": $input_sponsor_id, "User id": $input_username, "Password": $input_password}', 
  '{"Status": "json return?"}', 
  input_sponsor_id, 
  input_user_id);


Use a JSON construction function:
INSERT INTO audit_log
   (action, result, input_data, output_data, sponsor_id, user_id)
VALUES (
   1020,
   1,
   jsonb_build_object(
      'Sponsor id', :input_sponsor_id,
      'User id', :'input_username',
      'Password', :'input_password'
   ),
   '{"Status": "json return?"}',
   :input_sponsor_id,
   :input_user_id
);

Since you said you were using psql, I used psql variables (:input_user_id gives the value of the variable input_user_id). In other environments, you might need to reference variables in a different way.
